# if a graph G(V,E) is connected $|E|\geq|V|-1$

Tags: graphs, proof-techniques, connected

If a graph G(V,E) is connected the number of edges is at least the number of Vertices-1.
It is pretty evident if you think about it but how do i prove it formally?

Comment: By induction. Start with a set $S$ containing any arbitrary vertex $s$. Then add vertex $v$ which is neighbour of some vertex $u \in S$ along with edge $(u,v)$. At each point we will find some vertex and this procedure terminates as graph is connected we will cover all vertices. And at each point we use at least 1 edge so $|E| \ge |V| - 1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagine a process in which you start with the empty graph, and add the edges one by one. Keep track of the number of connected components. In the beginning, there are $|V|$ connected components. Each edge you add either belongs inside a connected component, or merges two connected components, and in any case, the number of connected components decreases by at most 1. Hence after adding $|E|$ edges, the number of connected components is at least $|V| - |E|$. If the graph is connected, $|V| - |E| \leq 1$, and so $|E| \geq |V| - 1$.